# how to login a cluster with robin DNS by ssh

Tags: ssh, dns

There is a cluster named "xxxx.com" with robin DNS.

`dig xxxx.com gives:`

`xxxx.com   3600 IN A aaa.bb.c.dd1`

`xxxx.com   3600 IN A aaa.bb.c.dd2`

`dig -x aaa.bb.c.dd1 gives:`

`dd1zzzzzzzz   3600 PTR   xxxx.com`

`dd1zzzzzzzz   3600 PTR   xxxx1.com`

and

`dig -x aaa.bb.c.dd2 gives:`

`dd2zzzzzzzz   3255 PTR   xxxx.com`

`dd2zzzzzzzz   3255 PTR   xxxx2.com`

My question is: if I just want to login
by command ssh username@xxxx.com without
any error, what should I do?

PS: I found the key of xxxx1.com and xxxx2.com are
different.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In `SSH` you can specify multiple identity files.

```
ssh -i /path/to/key1 -i /path/to/key2 username@xxxx.com
```

and if you dont want to type `-i` options everytime, create `~/.ssh/config` file as below

```
Host yyy
  Hostname xxxx.com
  User username
  IdentityFile /path/to/key1
  IdentityFile /path/to/key2
```

and you can always login using

```
ssh yyy
```

Comment: It seems not to work. I don't know what you mean by the identity files. I just copy the item for xxxx1.com and xxxx2.com to two files. so the file contains "xxxx1.com,aaa.bb.c.dd1 ssh-rsa .....". But when I run "ssh xxxx.com", I still got the message: The authenticity of host 'xxxx.com (aaa.bb.c.dd1)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is blablablablalba...
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? It is the same as before.

Comment: By Identity file, I mean the private key you use to login. What are the files you copied? I didnt get you. If you are using `public key Authentication` use the identity file lines or `-i` option.

Comment: Sorry I copy the items from known_hosts to file xxxx1 and xxxx2. So the file xxxx1 contains: "xxxx.com,aaa.bb.c.dd1 ssh-rsa blablabla....". Maybe it is not what you said? Thank you. How can I create the identity file?

Comment: This should help you https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2